# Bootstrap tabs in sections

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-tabs

I've started with a standard bootstrap tab control, and I want to split the tabs up into multiple sections. I've done this by making a div for the whole lot, and a div for each section, with it's own ul of tabs. This works fine, except that the active class is only cleared for inactive tabs in the same ul as the tab that's just become active, so I end up with up to one tab in each group appearing active. I've got a bit of js that uses Jquery to deactivate them all, then reactivate the one that's just become active (see below), but this feels like a bit of a hack. is there a way to tell bootstrap that all these ul's are actually one tab control?

```
let tabs = $('#tabs li');
tabs.find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    tabs.removeClass('active');
    $(e.target).parent('li').addClass('active');
});
```

Edit: The desired result of this is to have something like this:
`Section 1: { Tab1, Tab2, Tab3 }, Section 2: { Tab4, Tab5.active }`
Each section has it's own UL of tabs but they should still be treated as if they are a single set of tabs as they control only one tab pane, so only one tab should be active at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand correctly that you have 2 levels of tabs

```
Level one -> Tab1 active | Tab2   | Tab3   | Tab4   | Tab5   |
Level two -> Tab1.1  | Tab1.2   | Tab1.3 active| Tab1.4   | Tab1.5
```

this level 2 exists for some/all level 1 tabs. So what is the problem that a tab on level 2 stays active if not shown. Bootstrap uses this  for showing you the last selected tab on level 2. 
If you do not like it you have two posibillites

- to hack around to clear all active states (why?) OR
- you assign active when selecting a new tab level1 on some rules you need.

There is no need to clear all active level 2 to identify the active of the current level1 use the parent=active and child=active relation to identify the current tab on level2

**EDIT**
If you seperate by ul then for bootstrap its a different menue. Soif you want to use standard function seperate by styling  or with other css elements.Its no good desicion to break the "standard behavior" and then hack around. It will be hell mantaining and updating. So your "sections" should be css groups.

Examples are:

```
<li class="divider"></li> <!-- standard -->
<li class="my_seperator"></li> <!-- style my_seperator as you want with css
- you can make it look like ul 
if you copy the ul styling from bootstrap.css -->
```

Readmore in the [navs documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/navs/) or the [navbar documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/navbar/)

Comment: Hi @Codebreaker007, That's not quite what I want. I've edited the question to show what I want better. In short, all the tabs are at the same 'level', as you put it, just grouped in sections. Thanks for your answer.